# Python - How do I print always the word from a list found in a document to another list?

Tags: python, list

I want to have one list with the whole line and one list with the word, so i can export it later to excel.

my code always returns:

```
NameError: name 'word' is not defined
```

Here is my code:

```
l_lv = []
l_words = []

fname_in = "test.txt"
fname_out = "Ergebnisse.txt"


search_list =['kostenlos', 'bauseits', 'ohne Vergütung']

with open(fname_in,'r') as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        if any (word in line for word in search_list):
            l_lv.append(line)
            l_words.append(word)


print(l_lv)
print(l_words)
```

Edit:
I have a file with text in it, which looks somthing like fname_in and a list of word i want it to be search by (search_list). Always when the word is found in the file i want the word to be written into the list l_words and the sentance to the list l_lv.

The code for the lines works. But it doesn't return the words.

Here an exampel:

fname_in ='sentance1 with kostenlos in it. blablabla. another sentance2 with kostenlos in it. sentance3 with bauseits in it. blablabla. another sentance4 with bauseits in it. blablabla.'

As an result i wish to have:

l_lv = ['sentance1 with kostenlos in it', 'another sentance2 with kostenlos in it','sentance3 with bauseits in it', 'another sentance4 with bauseits in it']

l_words = ['kostenlos', 'kostenlos', 'bauseits', 'bauseits']

Comment: When you do `l_words.append(word)`, Python does not know what `word` is supposed to be because you never told it. Generator comprehensions don't leak their variables. We can't really say more without a [MCVE].

Comment: This has nothing to do with your title, you're not trying to `print` and you haven't really explained what this is supposed to do

Comment: please provide an example input and the expected output

Answer (score 0):

You do not have access to variables outside a list comprehension/generator expressions and so on. The error is valid in the sense that "word" is not defined when you try to append it.

```
l_lv = []
l_words = []

fname_in = "test.txt"
fname_out = "Ergebnisse.txt"


search_list =['kostenlos', 'bauseits', 'ohne Vergütung']

with open(fname_in,'r') as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        if any(word in line for word in search_list):
            l_lv.append(line)
            #for nested list instead of a flat list of words 
            #(to handle cases where more than 1 word matches in the same sentence.)
            #words_per_line = []
            for word in search_list:
                l_words.append(word)
                #words_per_line.append(word)
            #if words_per_line:
                #l_words.append(words_per_line)
print(l_lv)
print(l_words)
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `word` is only bound in the generator expression passed to `any()`, so it doesn't exist when you try to add it to a list later on.
It seems that you want to know not only if a word from the search list appeared in the line but also which ones. Try this:

```
for line in f_in:
    found = [word for word in search_list if word in line]
    if found:
        l_lv.append(line)
        l_words.append(found)
```

Note that this code assumes more than one word can appear in each line, and appends a list of words to l_lv for each line, meaning that l_lv is a list of lists.
If you want to append only the first word found in each line:

```
l_words.append(found[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid writing for loops on one line: it looses in readability and can cause problems.

Try this:

```
l_lv = []
l_words = []

input_file = "test.txt"
output_file = "Ergebnisse.txt"


search_list =['kostenlos', 'bauseits', 'ohne Vergütung']

with open(input_file,'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in search_list:
            if word in line:
                l_lv.append(line)
                l_words.append(word)
```